# Autorefreshing page with webBrowser and for()

Tags: c++, refresh, webbrowser-control, auto

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying visit webpage few time. Code:

```
this->webBrowser1->Navigate(webPage->Text);
int a = 0;
for(a=0;a<10;a++)
{
this->webBrowser1->Refresh();
Sleep(2000);
}
```

I can debug and run my project but it's doesn't working (I tried visit my web page with simple counter). Anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you not using META refresh tag http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Alternatives

Comment: I'm testing my project on my web page, but i would like use my program on others web pages (like google or facebook) so i don't have an acces to source.

Comment: Is this is all getting done in main thread? You should not be refreshing until the navigation is complete. Even then, you should not refresh in a for loop. Sleep would effectively sleep that thread, won't it? How would stuff get downloaded and displayed by browser control?

Comment: Uhm ... I don't know what you mean exactly, my english is weak. Can you give me some example?
I don't know how i can visit webpage many time without for loop. Maybe i shouldn't use refresh in for() but i have not other ideas.
I can wait for completly loading page and then refresh but it's still doesn't working.